# How to avoid redirect

Tags: java, http

I am working on a crawler and I try to download the link "http://devonline.com/". All the time I get code 301 with redirect on the same link.

How to avoid this redirect and retrieve a content?

This is how I make the request (file equals "/" in this case):

```
String request
        = "GET " + file
        + (file.endsWith("robots.txt") ? " HTTP/1.0\r\n" : " HTTP/1.1\r\n")
        //                " HTTP/1.1\r\n"
        + "User-Agent: " + CrawlerConfig.USER_AGENT + "\r\n"
        //                + ((!CrawlerConfig.SAVE_IMAGES) ? "Accept: text/html\r\n" : "")
        //                + "Accept: text/*\r\n"
        + (file.endsWith("robots.txt") ? "Connection: close\r\n" : "")
        + "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + "\r\n"/*
         * + body
         */;

outStream.write(request.getBytes("US-ASCII"));
outStream.flush();
```

Comment: What content? If it's a redirect, there isn't likely any useful response body content.

Comment: devonline.com have most likely got rules on their server config to deny a response to requests that do not look like they come from a genuine browser.

Comment: Don't "avoid" the redirect; follow it!

Answer (score 0):

You can't.
If webserver responds with a redirect, then extract the `Location` header and try yor luck there.

Actualy there is no universal solution.

I wrote my own grabber/crawler for 50-ish different websites. And almost all of them have uniqe way of working.

So when it comes to crawling, it's mostly a method of trying every possible action (if you don't have an API access).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a library like [Unirest](http://unirest.io/), instead of writing your own HTTP client.

Using a library has the following benefits.

- You don't need to write HTTP client code
- You can support HTTPS easily
- Redirects are automatically handled